# Get the product variations attributes values term ID and name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

In WooCommerce, I'm using `$product->get_variation_attributes()` to get the variations attributes for a product. This function returns an array with the names without the ID's.

Like this:

```
                   [pa_color-shirt] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => red
                            [7] => grey
                            [14] => yellow
                        )

                    [pa_color-sweater] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => red
                            [1] => green
                            [2] => blue
                            [3] => grey
                            [4] => yellow
                            [5] => pink
                            [6] => dark-blue
                        )
```

For the AJAX shop I'm creating I also need the ID's from the variations.
So I can append the Id's and the names to the select boxes (Like woocommerce does).
I searched around for days but couldn't find a solution.

I created this code:

```
if($product->has_child()) {
                $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
                $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                $variationsArray = array();
                foreach ($attributes as $attr => $attr_deets) {
                    $variationArray = array();
                    $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label($attr);
                    $variationArray["attribute_label"] = $attribute_label;
                    if (isset($attributes[$attr]) || isset($attributes['pa_' . $attr])) {
                        $attribute = isset($attributes[$attr]) ? $attributes[$attr] : $attributes['pa_' . $attr];
                        if ($attribute['is_taxonomy'] && $attribute['is_visible']) {
                            $variationArray["attribute_name"] = $attribute['name'];
                            $variationIds = array();
                            $variationNames = array();
                            $variationPrices = array();
                            foreach ($variations as $variation) {
                                if (!empty($variation['attributes']['attribute_' . $attribute['name']])) {
                                    array_push($variationIds, $variation['variation_id']);
                                    $taxonomy = $attribute['name'];
                                    $meta = get_post_meta($variation['variation_id'], 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, true);
                                    $term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);
                                    $variation_name = $term->name;
                                    array_push($variationNames, $variation_name);
                                    array_push($variationPrices, $variation['display_regular_price']);
                                }
                            }
                            $variationArray["variation_prices"] = $variationPrices;
                            $variationArray["variations"] = array_combine($variationIds, $variationNames);
                        }
                    }
                    array_push($variationsArray, $variationArray);
                }
            }

            $product_variations = $variationsArray;
```

This code returns https://hastebin.com/ecebewumoz.php

The code works but returns duplicate names and id's.

My questions is does anyone know how I could accomplish the same as `get_variation_attributes()` but with the ID's?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Update for WooCommerce versions 3+

```
foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $taxonomy => $terms_slug ){
    // To get the attribute label (in WooCommerce 3+)
    $taxonomy_label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy, $product );

    // Setting some data in an array
    $variations_attributes_and_values[$taxonomy] = array('label' => $taxonomy_label);

    foreach($terms_slug as $term){

        // Getting the term object from the slug
        $term_obj  = get_term_by('slug', $term, $taxonomy);

        $term_id   = $term_obj->term_id; // The ID  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  HERE
        $term_name = $term_obj->name; // The Name
        $term_slug = $term_obj->slug; // The Slug
        // $term_description = $term_obj->description; // The Description

        // Setting the terms ID and values in the array
        $variations_attributes_and_values[$taxonomy]['terms'][$term_id] = array(
            'name'        => $term_name,
            'slug'        => $term_slug
        );
    }
}
```

---

> Below WooCommerce version 3

I don't see any duplicate variations IDs in your raw data array… Your question is not very clear, so is difficult to guess what are the missing Ids you are looking at. Then I take the risk to answer and I suppose that the missing IDs are the term Ids from the attributes values…

To get this terms IDs, I use Wordpress function [**`get_term_by()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by), this way:

```
foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $taxonomy => $terms_slug ){
    // To get the taxonomy object
    $taxonomy_obj = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

    $taxonomy_name = $taxonomy_obj->name; // Name (we already got it)
    $taxonomy_label = $taxonomy_obj->label; // Label

    // Setting some data in an array
    $variations_attributes_and_values[$taxonomy] = array('label' => $taxonomy_obj->label);

    foreach($terms_slug as $term){

        // Getting the term object from the slug
        $term_obj  = get_term_by('slug', $term, $taxonomy);

        $term_id   = $term_obj->term_id; // The ID  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  HERE
        $term_name = $term_obj->name; // The Name
        $term_slug = $term_obj->slug; // The Slug
        // $term_description = $term_obj->description; // The Description

        // Setting the terms ID and values in the array
        $variations_attributes_and_values[$taxonomy]['terms'][$term_id] = array(
            'name'        => $term_name,
            'slug'        => $term_slug
        );
    }
}
```

And with:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($variations_attributes_and_values);echo '</pre>';
```

I will get this output, **with the real terms IDs for each attribute** for a product variations *(I have arranged the array output to get it more compact)*:

```js
Array(
    [pa_color] => Array(
        [label] => Color
        [terms] => Array(
            [8] => Array(
                [name] => Black
                [slug] => black'
            )
            [9] => Array(
                [name] => Blue
                [slug] => blue
            )
            [11] => Array(
                [name] => Green
                [slug] => green
            )
        ) 
    )
    [pa_bulk_quantity] => Array(
        [label] => Bulk quantity
        [terms] => Array(
            [44] => Array(
                [name] => Pack of 10 dozen
                [slug] => pack-of-10-dozen
            )
            [45] => Array(
                [name] => Case of 50 dozens
                [slug] => case-of-50-dozens
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my question was indeed unclear. What I meant was I wanted to get the variation id and name but that's not possible because a variation grey-red has an other variation ID than a variation with grey-yellow. So I need to experiment some more to get the desired result

Comment: @BoopathiD you should ask a new question…