# Output an array of terms names for WooCommerce product attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

This is my code and I need to display names of my each array:

**Black**

**Blue**

**Green**

```
foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $taxonomy => $terms_slug ){
// To get the taxonomy object
$taxonomy_obj = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

$taxonomy_name = $taxonomy_obj->name; // Name (we already got it)
$taxonomy_label = $taxonomy_obj->label; // Label

// Setting some data in an array
$variations_attributes_and_values[$taxonomy] = array('label' => $taxonomy_obj->label);

foreach($terms_slug as $term){

    // Getting the term object from the slug
    $term_obj  = get_term_by('slug', $term, $taxonomy);

    $term_id   = $term_obj->term_id; // The ID  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  HERE
    $term_name = $term_obj->name; // The Name
    $term_slug = $term_obj->slug; // The Slug
    $term_name = $term_obj->description; // The Description

    // Setting the terms ID and values in the array
    $variations_attributes_and_values[$taxonomy]['terms'][$term_obj->term_id] = array(
        'name'        => $term_obj->name,
        'slug'        => $term_obj->slug
    );
}}
```

And this is my arrays:

```
Array(
[pa_color] => Array(
    [label] => Color
    [terms] => Array(
        [8] => Array(
            [name] => Black
            [slug] => black'
        )
        [9] => Array(
            [name] => Blue
            [slug] => blue
        )
        [11] => Array(
            [name] => Green
            [slug] => green
        )
    ) 
))
```

How can I do it?

**/////NEW EDIT**

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($term_obj->name);echo '</pre>';
```

I used this code for showing names but just display last name!

Comment: Why you created such nested array. why don't  just create array like this :-`Array(
    [terms] => Array(
        [8] => Array(
            [name] => Black
            [slug] => black'
        )
        [9] => Array(
            [name] => Blue
            [slug] => blue
        )
        [11] => Array(
            [name] => Green
            [slug] => green
        )
    ) 
)`

Comment: What does your `get_term_by` function do? That's giving you `$term_obj` but we can't see how it is being initialised.

Comment: This is for woocommerce!

Comment: You should edit your question and add the relevant tags in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of my aswer's code: [Get the product variations attributes values term ID and name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497051/get-the-product-variations-attributes-values-term-id-and-name/42499333#42499333)

It has been done before Woocommerce 3 release.

Since woocommerce 3+ things have changed a little bit. You don't need all this code in the function. So here is an arranged version to feet your needs.

> **Remember** that you can have many attributes for a variable product, so you will need to use **`foreach`** loops to output separated values for each product attribute…

Here is the code:

```
foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $taxonomy => $terms_slug ){

    // To get the attribute label (in WooCommerce 3+)
    $taxonomy_label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy, $product );

    foreach($terms_slug as $term){

        // Getting the term object from the slug
        $term_name  = get_term_by('slug', $term, $taxonomy)->name;

        // Setting the terms ID and values in the array
        $attributes_and_terms_names[$taxonomy_label][$term] = $term_name;
    }
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($attributes_and_terms_names); echo '</pre>';
```

Then you will get:

```
Array
(
    [Color] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => Green
            [2] => Red
        )
)
```

Usage example output:

```
foreach ( $attributes_and_terms_names as $attribute_name => $terms_name ){
    // get the related attribute term names in a coma separated string
    $terms_string = implode( ', ', $terms_name );
    echo '<p>' . $attribute_name . ': ' . $terms_string . '</p>';
}
```

You will get:

> Color: Black, Green, Red